# How to mount volume from host to container

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am using docker in windows 10 and want to output logs from docker container to host `D:/Test`.

This is my log configuration:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;
    public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        _logger.LogError("Access Denied!!!");
        return View();
    }
```

This is my command to mount the volume

```
docker run -it -p 8081:80 -v D:/Test:/app/logs --name dockercoreapp10 dockercoreapp:v2
```

After run `docker inspect dockercoreapp10`, I could see the mount.

[image]

I could access `http://localhost:8081/`, but the log file did not create under `D:\Test`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What type of container are you working with?

After the run command, does the log file exist on the other side, within the container at the correct location /app/logs?

I've tried recreating your problem but using your run command, I have no problems.

(The logging stuff doesn't matter... you can put anything in the app/logs folder within your container to test it and it should appear in your mounted folder. On my side, I went into the app/logs folder and ran

```
touch test.txt
```

and test.txt appeared on the other side, no problems.)

Find the folder within the container. Put a file in there manually and check to see if it shows up on the other side. Or vice versa. My guess is that after the run command, you haven't actually placed any logs in the app/logs folder.

Comment: I am working with linux container. How can I switch to container to run `touch test.txt`?

Comment: You've got the first part already, the tag -it which should take you to the interactive terminal (inside the container) but you should also have bin/bash on the end of the command as well. Or, on a container that is already running, use docker exec command. https://ligerlearn.com/start-shell-running-docker-container/

Comment: I could see the `test.txt` file, but I am not sure why my log files did not create.

Comment: Then that isn't a problem with your mount, that's a problem with your code and however you're putting log files into the right place. Whatever log files you're trying to create aren't going to the correct place. When I started, what confused me is the linux directory structure and how it looks inside of a container. Try using a FIND to see if the log file is inside of your container somewhere, http://www.codecoffee.com/tipsforlinux/articles/21.html, however, I think you're now onto a problem of 'where to output my logs' and not 'why isn't mounting working'

Comment: Thanks, the linux container file path is case-sensitive, I need to change `/app/logs` to `/app/Logs`

Comment: Awesome! You're welcome. I'm glad everything worked out.